Angular Service State Not Updating for Subscribers Even After Using BehaviorSubject
I'm working on an Angular service that fetches rules from a secondary cart and updates a BehaviorSubject to manage the state. However, my subscribers are not receiving updates even after the state is updated.
Here is the code for my service:
import { Injectable, NgZone, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, filter, switchMap, map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { cloneDeep, get, isNil, filter as _filter, concat, isEmpty } from 'lodash';
import { SecondaryCartService } from './secondary-cart.service'; 
import { AppliedRuleActionInfo } from './applied-rule-action-info';  

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YourService {

    private secondaryCartService: SecondaryCartService = this.injector.get(SecondaryCartService);
    private state: BehaviorSubject<Array<AppliedRuleActionInfo>> = new BehaviorSubject<Array<AppliedRuleActionInfo>>(null);
    private ngZone = this.injector.get(NgZone);


  fetchRule(): Observable<Array<AppliedRuleActionInfo>> {
    return this.secondaryCartService.getMyCart()
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(2000),
        filter(cart => cart && !cart.IsPricePending),
        switchMap(cart => {
          if (!(get(cart, 'LineItems')?.length)) {
            return of(null);
          }
          return of(get(cart, 'AppliedRuleActionInfo'));
        }),
        map((rules) => {
          const currentState = this.state.value;
          if (!this.compareRules(currentState, rules) || !this.compareRules(rules, currentState) || isNil(rules)) {
            this.ngZone.run(() => this.state.next(cloneDeep(rules)));
          }
          return rules;
        }),
        shareReplay(1)
      );
  }

  getState(): Observable<Array<AppliedRuleActionInfo>> {
    return this.state.asObservable();
  }

  getAcion(): Observable<Array<AppliedRuleActionInfo>> {
    return this.getState().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        let filteredAppliedRuleAction = _filter(actions, action => action.Pending === true && !isEmpty(concat(get(action, 'ActionProductIds'))));
        return filteredAppliedRuleAction;
      })
    );
  }
}


Problem:
Even though this.state.next(cloneDeep(rules)) is called within the service, the getAcion method's subscribers are not receiving the updated state. I expect that whenever the state is updated, the subscribers of getPendingActionsForCart should receive the new state with the pending actions.
What I Have Tried:

Verified that this.state.next(cloneDeep(rules)) is indeed being
called.
Ensured this.state is a BehaviorSubject and initialized properly.
Checked that the observable returned by getState() is being
subscribed to correctly.

Additional Information:

The comparison logic in compareRules is just a simple JSON string
comparison for now.

fetchRulesFromSecondaryCart is being called, and the state is
supposed to be updated within the map operator.



is there a specific reason why you run the next call in ngZone run?

That approach was also part of my troubleshooting process to see if it would work. However, the issue persists regardless of whether I include NgZone or not.

Ah okay,
If you subscribe to your BehaviourSubject in the service, is there an update?
How do you use the Obervable in your components?
Maybe make a public readonly Observable instead of an return function like "public readonly state$ = this.state.asObservable();"

I've tried, but it's not reaching the subscriber.

do you subscribe to fetchRule() at all?
like this.YourService.fetchRule().subscribe() ?

In fact, there's a chain of subscriptions. The getAction() method within this service is subscribed to by another service. That service's method updates an observable, which is then returned by a method. This method is subsequently subscribed to in the component.
But the issue is here itself in getAction logs are not coming that means it's not reaching here

hmm can u bring it to stackblitz or sth, my imagination isn't good enough to follow right, i guess

Here it is
Stackblitz

This example isn't functional, but it illustrates the approach I'm using to follow the subscription chain.

I rebuild your problem , i hope nearly right and it works, i got some data in subjects.
Only difference i dont use this.injector.get()??
and structuredClone instead of cloneDeep
and dont use the zone run


@Component({
  selector: 'app-site-9',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: ``,
  styles: ``,
})
export class Site9Component {
  private Side9StateService = inject(Side9StateService);
  private Side9FilterService = inject(Side9FilterService);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.Side9StateService.fetchRule().subscribe();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.Side9StateService.getState().subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });

      this.Side9FilterService.getState().subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }, 10000);
  }
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class Side9FilterService {
  private side9StateService = inject(Side9StateService);
  private state: BehaviorSubject<Array<any> | null> =
    new BehaviorSubject<Array<any> | null>(null);

  constructor() {
    this.side9StateService.getAcion().subscribe((data) => {
      this.state.next(this.filterFN(data));
    });
  }

  filterFN(data: any): any {
    return data;
  }

  getState(): Observable<Array<any> | null> {
    return this.state.asObservable();
  }
}

@Injectable({ provided: 'root' })
export class Side9DataService {
  carts = [
    {
      LineItems: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      IsPricePending: false,
      AppliedRuleActionInfo: 'AppliedRuleActionInfo1',
    },
    {
      LineItems: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      IsPricePending: true,
      AppliedRuleActionInfo: 'AppliedRuleActionInfo1',
    },
    {
      IsPricePending: false,
      AppliedRuleActionInfo: 'AppliedRuleActionInfo2',
    },
    {
      IsPricePending: true,
      AppliedRuleActionInfo: 'AppliedRuleActionInfo2',
    },
    {
      LineItems: [],
      IsPricePending: false,
      AppliedRuleActionInfo: 'AppliedRuleActionInfo3',
    },
    {
      LineItems: [],
      IsPricePending: true,
      AppliedRuleActionInfo: 'AppliedRuleActionInfo3',
    },
  ];

  getMyCart(): Observable<any> {
    return of(this.carts[0]);
  }
}

@Injectable({ provided: 'root' })
export class Side9StateService {
  private side9DataService = inject(Side9DataService);
  private state: BehaviorSubject<Array<any> | null> =
    new BehaviorSubject<Array<any> | null>(null);

  fetchRule(): Observable<Array<any>> {
    return this.side9DataService.getMyCart().pipe(
      debounceTime(2000),
      filter((cart) => cart && !cart.IsPricePending),
      switchMap((cart) => {
        if (!get(cart, 'LineItems')?.length) {
          return of(null);
        }
        return of(get(cart, 'AppliedRuleActionInfo'));
      }),
      map((rules) => {
        const currentState = this.state.value;
        console.log(rules);
        this.state.next(structuredClone(rules));

        return rules;
      }),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }

  getState(): Observable<Array<any> | null> {
    return this.state.asObservable();
  }

  getAcion(): Observable<Array<any> | null> {
    return this.getState().pipe(
      map((actions) => {
        return actions;
      })
    );
  }
}
function get(cart: any, arg1: string) {
  return cart[arg1];
}




I truly appreciate your quick response in assisting me, but unfortunately, the use of StructuredClone isn't proving helpful for my situation.

but it shouldn't make a difference
my approach works with both, respectively makes no difference

The difference here is that I'm not making calls to getState and getAction directly from the calling component. In my case, there is another service (e.g., Side9FilterService) which reads the values from getAction() and then updates another observable within the service. I am then reading this particular observable from a component using a get method within the same service file.

i updated my approach, it works like it should i guess? do you see sth different to yours?

The difference lies in how I invoke the getAction method from a service file, which updates a BehaviorSubject, and then subscribe to that specific observable from the component. Whereas, you're directly subscribing to all methods from the component.

so refactor my approach that it matches your problem. its hard to help if you don't bring a good example.

we need to have another service like this
export class Side9ActionService {
private state: BehaviorSubject<Array | null> = new BehaviorSubject<Array | null>(null);
constructor(private side9StateService: Side9StateService) {
this.side9StateService.getAcion().subscribe((data) => {
this.state.next(data);
});
}
getState(): Observable<Array | null> {
return this.state.asObservable();
}
}
and from the component Side9ActionService.getState.subscribe

but i hade done this with the side9filter service

Here is the updated version of stackblitz

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
